# Developing tools for Poser (Pro)

Tags: .net, winapi

As a software engineer, I sometimes use Poser Pro to create artwork to insert in my applications. It's useful to provide visual reminders to the users of the applications. For example, an image of a man/woman when a person has provided a gender as additional feedback to the "select gender" combo box. Or a house when they need to enter an address. And often just as filler for large forms which normally would contain lots of whitespace. And of course it's useful for splash-screens too. I often use my own rendered images before the application is restyled by a professional stylist. (Who often replaces the art by real pictures.)
(Poser runs on Mac OS-X and Windows 32/64 but I only use the WIN32/64 version.)

However, Poser is a rendering application that contains lots and lots of models. And unfortunately these models aren't really neatly organized. (At least, to my opinion.) I can get a good overview of the models I have from within the application but I have no solution to just print a complete overview, to make searching for a specific model easier. So, I want to write my own tool to provide me the additional functions that I would like to have.

Unfortunately, the Internet is full of information about Poser and most isn't really related to developing your own add-ons for it. Or information about all the file formats used by this application.

So, I'm wondering... Are there more developers here who use Poser (or similar applications) to provide artwork for their applications? And if so, do you know good technical sites with information about the file formats used by Poser and how they relate to one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct response to your question, but have you tried using Daz Studio in stead, specifically the included scripting capabilities and/or [SDK](http://www.daz3d.com/i/software/daz_studio3/developer?_m=d)?

Comment: Well, I had to decide between Poser and Daz Studio about three years ago and then decided to use Poser. I did an upgrade for the 64-bits rendering engine of Poser, which is great when you're creating huge images. Unfortunately, switching to Daz Studio means I have to re-install my 1800+ models again, which just takes too much time. (Then again, Daz studio is free, and the advanced version costs me about $60, so I am still considering to just buy it.) However, for now I need a Poser solution.